# Do system font (TTF/OTF) forms of the Kepler Project fonts (kpfonts) exist?

Tags: fonts, kpfonts

I have recently fallen in love with the `kpfonts` package. Whilst it looks great in both body text and TikZ pictures, my current issue is that I cannot create images in external programs containing this typeface and must resort to Pagella or similar (I don't appear to have Palatino).

I imagine that the fonts as defined in the `kpfonts` LaTeX package have lots of extra metrics information that would be lost in a TTF/OTF file, but do TTF and/or OTF versions of at least `kp serif` regular exist?

Comment: Unfortunately not yet. I seem to remember that Christophe Caignaert is at least thinking about an OpenType version.

Comment: I guess the best you can do is combine external text-less graphics with `pgf` labels where possible, and use [Palatino-like](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Palatino#Variants_and_similar_typefaces) fonts anywhere else.

Comment: you want to use kpfonts within an application like Illustrator or Inkscape? I've myself been able to import the kpfonts fonts provided on CTAN to use them directly in Illustrator. I have not tried yet with Inkscape.

Comment: @ pluton: That's the idea. Unfortunately the `kpfonts` package doesn't seem to have *.pfm files. How did you import them?

Comment: @Richard: I had success by copying the kpfonts fonts in:
C:\Program Files\Common Files\Adobe\Fonts. They would then be available within the font menu of Illustrator: you have to pay attention to their extension .pfm, .afm, otf... I'm still investigating for a sue within Inkscape.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You probably can create the OTF-files yourself. Get [fontforge](http://fontforge.sourceforge.net/), open the *.pfb and whatever fontforge requires and try file/generate from the menu. Take care that you are allowed to write the new file into the same directory.

I did not try myself, but there is a chance it works.

Alexander

EDIT: It works in the way described above. Tried with one of the kpfonts.

Comment: @ Keks: Sorry for the delay in marking this answered - I got into contact with Christophe to ensure that he was fine with me doing this for personal use as I'm not too well versed on the intersection of the various licenses in play. He's fine with it, so thanks for this great suggestion.

Answer (score 2):

Since 2020-06-20, an experimental OTF implementation of `kpfonts` is available at CTAN as [kpfonts-otf](https://ctan.org/pkg/kpfonts-otf).

Answer (score -1):

1. Find a way to install the original Type 1 fonts on your system. Probably, it's not complex.
2. As **Keks Dose** suggested, but using **FontLab Studio** or **TransType**. But they are commercial.