# ConTeXt: strange issue with typescript

Tags: fonts, context

I am trying to use some fonts installed on my computer with `typescript` as explained [in this post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/429642/213111) in order to create some fancy titles but I have a strange issue with `\setuphead`.

Here is an example with `\switchtobodyfont` in `\setuphead`'s `style`:

```
\starttypescriptcollection [fira]
  \starttypescript [sans] [fira]
    \setups[font:fallback:sans]
    \definefontsynonym [Sans]           [file:FiraSans-Regular.otf]       [features=default]
    \definefontsynonym [SansItalic]     [file:FiraSans-RegularItalic.otf] [features=default]
    \definefontsynonym [SansBold]       [file:FiraSans-Bold.otf]          [features=default]
    \definefontsynonym [SansBoldItalic] [file:FiraSans-BoldItalic.otf]    [features=default]
    \definefontsynonym [SansCaps]       [file:FiraSans-Regular.otf]       [features={default,smallcaps}]
  \stoptypescript

  \starttypescript [mono] [fira]
    \setups[font:fallback:mono]
    \definefontsynonym [Mono]     [file:FiraMono-Medium.otf] [features=default]
    \definefontsynonym [MonoBold] [file:FiraMono-Bold.otf]   [features=default]
  \stoptypescript

  \starttypescript [math] [fira]
    \definefontsynonym [MathRoman] [file:Fira-Math.otf] [features=mathextra]
  \stoptypescript

  \starttypescript [fira]
    \definetypeface [\typescriptone] [rm] [serif] [modern] [default]
    \definetypeface [\typescriptone] [ss] [sans]  [fira]   [default]
    \definetypeface [\typescriptone] [tt] [mono]  [fira]   [default]
    \definetypeface [\typescriptone] [mm] [math]  [fira]   [default]
    \quittypescriptscanning
  \stoptypescript
\stoptypescriptcollection



\setuphead[section][style={\switchtobodyfont[fira,sans]}]

\starttext
  \section{section 1}
  \section{section 2}
  \section{section 3}
\stoptext
```

[image]

What do happens here?

Comment: The line endings for each `\definefontsynonym` settings add spaces when you load the font for the first time, to avoid this you can move the typescript settings in a separate file (e,g. `type-fira.tex`) which is loaded `\switchtobodyfont` or you preload the typescript with `\usetypescript[fira]`.

Comment: Neat, it works like a charm! Why does it add spaces for first load of the font?

Comment: @WolfgangSchuster: Your comment-answers are awesome. For posterity, it may be helpful to others to see them as answer-answers to make them more visible. Especially when there's a sweet checkmark for emphasis. (I sometimes overlook answers in comments, given the nature of the SE network's Q&A format.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you write typescripts for a new font ConTeXt stores these settings but no fonts are loaded at this point, this allows complicated typescript defintions where the upright, italic. etc styles can be changed when the fonts are loaded which is usefull for large font families.

Once you create a typeface with the `\definetypeface` commands ConTeXt loads all the necessary typescripts which can be a problem when you do this within regular text, because many line ends in typescripts blocks produce extra spaces with appear now in the output.

In the example below I create a simple typescript for the `TeX Gyre Pagella` font. The problem is that I load the font in a `\hbox` which flushes all spaces from my typescripts in horizontal mode.

```
\starttypescript [serif] [tex-gyre-pagella]
    \definefontsynonym [Serif]           [file:texgyrepagellaregular]    [features=default]
    \definefontsynonym [SerifItalic]     [file:texgyrepagellaitalic]     [features=default]
    \definefontsynonym [SerifBold]       [file:texgyrepagellabold]       [features=default]
    \definefontsynonym [SerifBoldItalic] [file:texgyrepagellabolditalic] [features=default]
\stoptypescript

\starttypescript [tgy]
    \definetypeface [tgy] [rm] [serif] [tex-gyre-pagella]
\stoptypescript

\starttext

\ruledhbox{\strut\space}

\ruledhbox{\strut\space\switchtobodyfont[tgy]}

\ruledhbox{\strut\space\ntimes{\kern\spaceamount}{5}}

\stoptext
```

Each linebreak in my typescript at the end of the `\definefontsynonym` settings creates a visible space and a additional space is created from the `\definetypeface` setting.

[image]

To avoid this problem you can drop the `typescript` environment for the `\definetypeface` commands which loads all necessary typescript before you load the fonts, e.g.

```
\definetypeface [tgy] [rm] [serif] [tex-gyre-pagella]
```

or you preload the typescript you want to use before you load it in your document, e.g.

```
\usetypescript[tgy]
```